# pythonic way to map set of strings to integers

Tags: python

Is there shorter way to do this?

```
g_proptypes = {
    'uint8' : 0
    'sint8' : 1,
    'uint16' : 2,
    'sint16' : 3,
    'uint32' : 4,
... # more strings
}
```

The dict is necessary as I'll have the string with me and need to find the corresponding integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have your strings in an iterable you can do:

```
g_proptypes = dict((string, i) for i, string in enumerate(string_list))
```

Comment: I checked. It gives {0:'uint8', 1:'sint8'...}. I need the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

`>>> lst = ['uint8','sint8','unit16','sint16','uint32','etc']`

`>>> g_proptypes = dict(map(reversed,enumerate(lst)))`

`>>> g_proptypes`

`{'sint16': 3, 'unit16': 2, 'uint8': 0, 'etc': 5, 'sint8': 1, 'uint32': 4}`

Answer (score 0):

you can do this if the integers are sequential : http://codepad.org/o7ryZ09O

```
myList = ['uint8','sint8','uint16','sint16','uint32']
myStr = 'uint16'
myNum = myList.index(myStr);
print myNum;
```

Comment: It may be useful to ask OP if it was intentional that he was mapping the string to the index in the array.